# How to retain only one surface after merging two surface point clouds of an object?

Tags: 3d, open3d

Hi I am using Open3D to register two point clouds and merging them. Like in 2d we have blending options, is there any option in point cloud? My aim is to merge pcd of object taken around the object and merge them to get 3d model after estimating pose of each pcd using icp and pose graph optimisation.